# Flutter firestore Data can be use as a password?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

when I generate data inside the collection in firebase, I want that string to use a password,
like.
'
if(Snapshot == passcode){
return LogedinPage();
else
{
Text("Something went wrong")
}
'

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to store your users password as data in your Firebase Realtime Database? If so that's really a bad practice and I doubt marketplaces will share your app to their userbase with that logic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.